# This site can’t be reached

Tags: wordpress

I am using Google Cloud Platform with the Bitnami Stack, and my website is: https://www.hienthaoshop.com/.

This morning I got this error:

> This site can’t be reached www.hienthaoshop.com refused to connect.
>   Try:
>   Checking the connection
>   Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And now I cannot connect to my website and admin as well.

What can I do now? Has anyone experienced this like me? I think this is the hosting problem, but I cannot contact Google support because my support package is Bronze only.

Comment: You haven't given any relevant information about your web server stack, so it's impossible to say why this has happened beyond the general information given in the linked Q&A. Specifically: Your server is not running a web server on port 443. You will need to investigate and determine why that is.

Comment: Hi Michael Hampton, I am not IT expert. I deployed WordPress website about 1.5 years ago on Google Cloud which using Bitnami stack. It is quite stable until yesterday. What kind of web server stack I should give now. It took me a year to make this website and now I don't know what happened. Could you help me, please?

Comment: I already solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Try to ping your site.
- Check internet options, LAN connections.
- Check if your site has been added as trusted sites.
- Try to open site in another browser,
- Check your proxy settings,
- open cmd and there: ipconfig /release and after that restar your PC.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. This is not a matter of internet connection. My website has been down for all of the other devices. This is the hosting problem but I cannot contact Google Cloud Support